# Hide bootstrap modal popup

Tags: phantomjs

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create();
var filename = 'demo.png';
webpage.open('https://www.example.com/', function() {    
webpage.render(filename);
phantom.exit();});
```

In the above code when the example web site loads it displays a bootstrap popup. now in phantom js i want to take a screenshot of the web page without the popup. please help me on how to hide this popup through phantomjs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide/turn modal off before making a screenshot:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var filename = 'demo.png';
page.open('https://www.example.com/', function() {    

    // Delay script by a second to give
    // javascript some time to load and execute modal
    setTimeout(function(){

        page.evaluate(function(){
            // You'll need to find the modal id to hide it programmatically
            $('#themodal').modal('hide');
        });   

        page.render(filename);

        phantom.exit();
    }, 
    1000);

});
```

Another way is to just remove the modal window elements from DOM:

```
        page.evaluate(function(){
            // These classes are for Bootstrap 4
            $('.modal, modal-backdrop').remove();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your resposne, But the above code is not working still i can able to see the popup got displayed. also i have increased the timeout to 8sec but still the popup is displayed. please let me is there any other setting i might be missing ?

Comment: Did you replace "#themodal" from the example to the actual ID of the modal on your target site?

Comment: Yes, i did, also page to webpage type is been updated, but no luck

Comment: Added a suggestion to the answer.